# Why are women not allowed to read from the Torah in conservative Judaism?

Tags: orthodox, reform-judaism, conservative-judaism

I'm not Jewish myself, but my wife is and per my understanding of Jewish tradition, this means our children are as well. My wife's preference is for either Reconstructionist or Reform denomination because as I understand it, Conservative and Orthodox denominations do not permit women to read from the Torah.

Why is this not permitted in Conservative/Orthodox Judaism?

Comment: @JoelK I think that might answer my question, but I'm having a very difficult time understanding the answers due to the abundance of Jewish/Hebrew (?) terminology. Is there a manner to edit my question to ask for something either devoid of that terminology or with the definitions provided?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Pyroetchnical and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I think that standard best-practice is to ask on that question for someone to de-jargon it. I think there's also some meta question somewhere that has a glossary, I'll see if I can find it. But regarding this question, I think lumping Orthodox and Conservative together is a bit inaccurate. Basically all Orthodox does not allow women reading the Torah (and the 'Orthodox' congregations that allow it are often quite controversial), while my understanding of Conservative is that many do allow women cantors and Torah readers.

Comment: If your wife is halachically (halacha is Jewish law) Jewish, then your kids are as well. My understanding of Conservative Judaism is that women do indeed read from the Torah. Orthodox Judaism does not permit this during regular services for a number of reasons, partly for modesty (women and men do not mix in Orthodox synagogues), partly because of tradition, partly because of public policy. Hope this helps.

Comment: [We are discussing this question in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51262213#51262213)

Comment: @mbloch It's not really a "modesty" problem. Women don't read because of *kavod hatzibbur* which is an entirely different concept.

Comment: @DanF gam v’gam. Can you imagine a woman reading in the middle of men? Do women come to the sefer for birkat hagomel? Same issue for why a woman carrying a baby for a Brit Mila who gives it over to a man rather than enter the assembly of men

Comment: I am a woman who has read Torah in a Conservative congregation.  There might be some that don't allow this, but it's not universal.